# Is there an analytic approximation to integral of this form?

Tags: integration, analysis, approximation

Started working on trying to find an analytical approximation to this integral and not getting very far. Any assistance or direction is greatly appreciated! Thanks Vince

$$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\frac{a}{(1+bt_p)^2}e^{-(\frac{at_p}{1+bt_p})}}{\sqrt{(c + (1+bt_p)^2)^2 + d(t-t_p)}}dt_p$$

Found the above equation may be a possible Laplace form from [An Introduction to Asymptotic Analysis by Simon J. A Malham](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/ae.pdf) (see Chap4. pg 31 onward):

$$I(x) = \int_{u}^{v} f(t)e^{x~\phi(t)}$$ with $t = t_p$ and the limits are 
$v=t$ and $u=0$ gives:
$$f(t_p) = \frac{\frac{a}{(1+bt_p)^2}}{\sqrt{(c + (1+bt_p)^2)^2 + d(v-t_p)}}  $$
and taking $x =-1$ and $\phi(t_p)$ as: 
$$\phi(t_p) = e^{\frac{at_p}{1+bt_p}}$$
Next I need to work through the boundary term at the limits of 0 to t (t is the final time of the filtration period which is a constant and known experimental value from my data sets):
$$ -\frac{f(t_p)}{\phi^{'}(t_p)}\cdot~e^{-\phi(t_p)}$$

and new integral term: $$ \int_{u}^{v} \frac{d}{dt_p}\left(\frac{f(t_p)}{\phi^{'}(t_p)}\right)\cdot e^{x\phi(tp)}dt_p$$

Next steps are going to take me some time but will update as I progress through this problem but of course welcome any edits or additions.

Comment: Approximation in what sense?  There are a lot of parameters, what are there approximate values?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas: Opps! A bit of background...the equation is a model of membrane filtration considering pore blocking, pore constriction and surface fouling. The parameters are composites of physical parameters that I have experimental data for and trying to get best estimates based on a non-linear regression fit. My non-linear regression code won't accept the integral as input so I'm hoping to find an approximate analytic equation to replace the integral. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that the integral has a Laplace form and may be reduced asymptotically to an analytic form. I'm new to this approach but seems like a possible route.